# Which SchemaType in Mongoose is best for a timestamp?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I'm using Mongoose, MongoDB, and Node.js.

I would like to define a schema where one of its fields is a date\timestamp.

I would like to use this field in order to return all of the records that have been updated in the last 5 minutes.

Due to the fact that in Mongoose I can't use the Timestamp() method, I understand that my only option is to use the following JavaScript method:

```
time : { type: Number, default: (new Date()).getTime() }
```

It's probably not the most efficient way for querying a humongous database.
Is there a more efficient way of implementing this.

Is there a way to implement this with Mongoose and be able to use a MongoDB timestamp?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

**Edit - 20 March 2016**

Mongoose now support [timestamps for collections](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/History.md#4111--2015-10-12).

Please consider the [answer of @bobbyz below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34398826/1139105). Maybe this is what you are looking for.

## Original answer

Mongoose supports a `Date` type (which is basically a timestamp):

```
time : { type : Date, default: Date.now }
```

With the above field definition, any time you save a document with an unset `time` field, Mongoose will fill in this field with the current time.

Source: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but what i'm trying to understand is the best way to query for returning all the records that have been updated in the last 5 minutes. Do you mean I should use :                date : {$gt: ((Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000))-300)}

Comment: @user1103897 you can construct a Date object directly and use it with $gt like this:

    var now = new Date();
    var fiveminago = new Date(now.getTime() - 5*60*1000);

then query with {date : {$gt:fiveminago}}

Comment: Should probably be `Date.now` instead of `Date.now()`.

Comment: +1 elmigranto, Mongoose docs example uses Date.now http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: Explanation: `Date.now` because `Date.now` is a function that will be run when you make objects. `Date.now()` is the date that your `models.js` was parsed. Ie, if you use `Date.now()` all your objects will have the same date, and that will be the date `models.js` was parsed.

Comment: Your link "timestamps for collections" is leading to a blank page. Can you update your answer, pls?

Answer (score 144):

The current version of Mongoose (v4.x) has time stamping as a built-in option to a schema:

```
var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema( {name: String}, {timestamps: true} );
```

This option adds `createdAt` and `updatedAt` properties that are timestamped with a `Date`, and which does all the work for you. Any time you update the document, it updates the `updatedAt` property. [Schema Timestamps Docs.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps)

Comment: Thank you, the docs were not clear that one could use `timestamps: true` instead of overriding the names using `timestamps: {...}`.

Comment: @tar I assume it's still working, but the 4.x docs used to specifically mention `timestamps: true`, so there may be some extra considerations needed going forward. (Maybe they're deprecating it? You're right, the docs aren't very clear for this option.)

Answer (score 29):

In case you want custom names for your `createdAt` and `updatedAt`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');  
const { Schema } = mongoose;
    
const schemaOptions = {
  timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' },
};

const mySchema = new Schema({ name: String }, schemaOptions);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This was super helpful. Was searching documentation but couldn't find how to do this. Thanks again for sharing.

Answer (score 10):

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    name : { type: String }
});

ItemSchema.set('timestamps', true); // this will add createdAt and updatedAt timestamps
```

Docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps

Comment: We could just pass the `{ timestamps: true }` as second argument in `new Schema({}, {<here>})`.

Comment: How Can I change timestamps createdAt and updatedAt format is like (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss)

Answer (score 3):

Mongoose now supports the timestamps in schema.

```
const item = new Schema(
  {
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  { timestamps: true },
);
```

This will add the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields on each record create.

Timestamp interface has fields

```
  interface SchemaTimestampsConfig {
    createdAt?: boolean | string;
    updatedAt?: boolean | string;
    currentTime?: () => (Date | number);
  }
```

This would help us to choose which fields we want and overwrite the date format.

Comment: Thats also the Typescript interface to use e.g. via `import { SchemaTimestampsConfig } from 'mongoose'`

Answer (score 1):

```
new mongoose.Schema({
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    completed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to use this field in order to return all the records that have been updated in the last 5 minutes.

This means you need to update the date to "now" every time you save the object. Maybe you'll find this useful: [Moongoose create-modified plugin](https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose-createdmodified)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **timestamps:true** along with **toDateString** to get created and updated date.

```
    const SampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    accountId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
    }, {
       timestamps: true,
       get: time => time.toDateString()
    });
```

[Sample doc in Mongo DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGg65.png)

Answer (score -8):

First : `npm install mongoose-timestamp`

Next: `let Timestamps = require('mongoose-timestamp')`

Next: `let MySchema = new Schema`

Next: `MySchema.plugin(Timestamps)`

Next : `const Collection = mongoose.model('Collection',MySchema)`

Then you can use the `Collection.createdAt` or `Collection.updatedAt` anywhere your want.

Created on: Date Of The Week Month Date Year 00:00:00 GMT

Time is in this format.

Comment: It's built into Mongoose so avoid using plugins