# bulk.insert(doc) default value not able to inserted MongoDB nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, bulkinsert

I have inserted 100k records, I have uploaded records batch-wise successfully. But, If I use the `bulk.insert(doc)` the default value not inserted using mongoose and Nodejs. like `createdAt` and `updatedAt` field as default value not inserted. I trying to add the options `setDefaultsOnInsert: true` `bulk.insert` no option to add the value. Currently, I added my code. Please help me out for advance.

### **code**

```
let data = req.body;
    var bulk = callDispositionModel.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    var counter=0
    data.forEach(doc1 => {
        bulk.insert(doc1);
        if (counter % 5000 == 0) {
            bulk.execute();
            bulk = callDispositionModel.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
            counter = 0;
        }

    counter++
    })

    if (counter > 0) {
        bulk.execute(function(err,result) {
        if(err){
            console.log(`err `, err)
        }else{
            console.log(`result `, result)
            return res.send({success: true, message:'data uploaded successfully')
        }
        });
    }
```

### **Schema or Model**

```
let dispositionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : {type: String, default: null},
   mobile : {type : String, default: null},
    remarks : {type: String, default:null},
    duration: {type : String, default: null},
    amount : {type : Number, default: 0},
    date : {type : String, default: null},
    time : {type : String, default: null},
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

const disposition = mongoose.model('disposition', dispositionSchema);
export default disposition;
```

### **Data**

It's inserted the data in mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6098e6d007e2804b9c1f8317"),
   "name" : "senthil",
    "amount" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6098e6d007e2804b9c1f8316"),
    "name" : "periyas",
    "amount" : 0
}
```

But, I have expected the output

**Expected Data**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6098e6d007e2804b9c1f8317"),
   "name" : "senthil",
    "amount" : 0,
    "mobile" : null,
    "remarks" : null,
    "createdAt": "2021-05-07T13:55:34.233Z"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6098e6d007e2804b9c1f8316"),
    "name" : "periyas",
    "mobile" : null,
    "remarks" : null,
    "createdAt": "2021-05-07T13:55:34.233Z"
}
```

Comment: can show schema? have you defined timestamps: true in your schema options?

Comment: @turivishal yes I updated the schema, please check now

Comment: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34398826/8987128) how to enable auto timestamp in schema, and you don't have to put createdAt and updatedAt fields in your schema just remove that 2 fields.

Comment: @turivishal,  I have enabled already ```timestamps: true``` not worked. Another ```remarks``` field is not stored in the default value.

Comment: what npm you are using `mongoose` or `mongodb`, and what version?

Comment: I used ```mongoose``` npm package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bulk insert support [request in mongoose github](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2366), and read one of the [comment](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2366#issuecomment-359275386) by moderator:

> *The `initializeUnorderedBulkOp()` and `initializeOrderedBulkOp()` api methods, which is "soft deprecated" by mongodb. It has been replaced by the [bulkWrite() API](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/crud/crud.rst#bulk-write-models), which is part of MongoDB's core CRUD spec and thus is much more widely implemented. In particular, mongoose has a [Model.bulkWrite()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite) function as of 4.9.0 that has validation, casting, promises, and ref depopulating.*

You can use `bulkWrite()` something like:

```
let data = req.body;
let bulk = [];    
data.forEach((doc1) => {
    bulk.push({ "insertOne": { "document": doc1 } });
    if (bulk.length === 5000) {
        callDispositionModel.bulkWrite(bulk).then((result) => {});
        bulk = [];
    }
})
if (bulk.length > 0) {
    callDispositionModel.bulkWrite(bulk).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.insertedCount);
        return res.send({success: true, message: 'all data uploaded successfully'})
    });
}
```

Comment: If I using ```bulkWrite``` API call. It taking too much time 5min. I have nearly 150k records. So I used the ```batchSize``` insertion 5000 records per call it will be inserted.

Comment: you can apply same logic of batchSize in bulkWrite, i have just added example only for understanding, you can modify as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
let dispositionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name : {type: String, default: null},
 mobile : {type : String, default: null},
 remarks : {type: String, default:null},
 duration: {type : String, default: null},
 amount : {type : Number, default: 0},
 date : {type : String, default: null},
 time : {type : String, default: null},
 createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now },
 updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

To

```
let dispositionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name : {type: String, default: null},
 mobile : {type : String, default: null},
 remarks : {type: String, default:null},
 duration: {type : String, default: null},
 amount : {type : Number, default: 0},
 date : {type : String, default: null},
 time : {type : String, default: null},
 createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now },
 updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now }
}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'createdAt' , updatedAt: 'updatedAt'} });
```

[More detail here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps)

Comment: ```createdAt``` and ```updatedAt``` fields are ok. Some other fields like ```time```, ```date```, ``` ```remarks``` fields doesn't store in MongoDB.

Comment: cannot set the default value null

Comment: ```remarks``` field doesn't have in data, default value inserted in MongoDB. But, the remarks field not inserted. Currently, inserted three fields, I expected 6 fields to be inserted in MongoDB. 3 fields user interaction value and 3 fields schema default values

Answer (score 0):

you can now set a timestamps option on the Schema to have Mongoose handle this for you:

```
var dispositionSchema = new Schema({..}, { timestamps: true });
```

Comment: ```remarks: null``` default value null doesn't store in the MongoDB.